# How to str_split text to few column using purrr

Tags: r, dictionary, dplyr, purrr, strsplit

I have data frame and I want to split column to 3 another:

```
df<-data.frame(x=1:5,y=paste0("num-",1:5,"-ber"))
df
  x         y
1 1 num-1-ber
2 2 num-2-ber
3 3 num-3-ber
4 4 num-4-ber
5 5 num-5-ber
```

Result must be something like that:

```
 x  y1 y2  y3
1 1 num  1 ber
2 2 num  2 ber
3 3 num  3 ber
4 4 num  4 ber
5 5 num  5 ber
```

I'm trying variation something like this:

```
df%>%
  purrr::map_chr(stringr::str_split(y,pattern="-"))
```

But without any positive results

Thx!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `separate` from `tidyr` which automatically picks up the delimiter if the `sep` is not specified.  In this case, it is `-`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
    separate(y, into= paste0('y', 1:3))
#  x  y1 y2  y3
#1 1 num  1 ber
#2 2 num  2 ber
#3 3 num  3 ber
#4 4 num  4 ber
#5 5 num  5 ber
```

---

Or a `base R` option would be to read with `read.table` specifying the `sep` as `-` and `cbind` with the 'x' column

```
cbind(df['x'], read.table(text=as.character(df$y), sep="-", col.names = paste0("y", 1:3)))
```

Comment: this is very good decision, but I hope to see answer using `purrr`

Comment: @jyjek  It will be inefficient to loop through each element in `map` and then do the split.  But, if you insist `df %>% pull(y) %>%  map_df(~ str_split(.x, '-')[[1]] %>% t %>% as_tibble ) %>% rename_all(funs(paste0("y", 1:3))) %>% bind_cols(df['x'], .)`

Comment: Thx a lot for this